# Wrap every image in a article with the "href" of parent link title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3><a class="title" href="page1.html">Post Title</a></h3>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="imageOne.png" alt="" />
        <p>Some text.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3><a class="title" href="page2.html">Post Title</a></h3>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="imageTwo.png" alt="" />
        <p>Some text.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <!-- [...] -->
</ul>
```

What I want to do in JS/jQuery: wrap all the images with a link with the same `href` attribute of `a.title`.

And I coded up something like this in jQuery, but the result gives to me is only the `href` of the first `a.title`:

```js
$("ul li ul li img").each(function() {
  $(this).wrap("<a href='" + $("ul li a.title").attr("href") + "'> </a>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3><a class="title" href="page1.html">Post Title</a></h3>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="imageOne.png" alt="" />
        <p>Some text.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3><a class="title" href="page2.html">Post Title</a></h3>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="imageTwo.png" alt="" />
        <p>Some text.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <!-- [...] -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work (if you fix your HTML<sup>†</sup>).

```
$("ul li ul li img").each(function(){
    $(this).wrap("<a href='"+ $(this).closest("li:has(h3)").find('a.title').attr("href") + "'> </a>");
});
```

*(could also use `li:has(a.title)` instead of `li:has(h3)`...)*

If your markup is fixed like that, you could also retrieve the value with:

```
$(this).parents('li').find('a.title').attr('href')
```

---

†:

- The `a` elements need a closing tag.
- The second `a` element needs the `title` class.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't/fix touch the code...However your second line of code works -perfectly- and I learned some interesting things with your answer!

Answer (score 1):

When you access an attribute or property with attr or prop in jQuery, it will only give you the value from the *first* element in the result of the selector.  In your case, your selector grabs all "ul li a.title" on the page, and so the attribute grabbed is from the first only.

What you want is the *closest* 'ul li a.title', and to accomplish this you can use the 'closest' jQuery function:

```
$("ul li ul li img").each(function(){
    var closestHref = $(this).closest('a.title').attr('href');
    $(this).wrap("<a href='"+ closestHref + "'> </a>");
});
```

EDIT: Per Felix comment below, .closest() only searches ancestors.  Please see his answer for the correct selector.

Comment: `.closest` only searchers *ancestors*. `a.title` is not an ancestor of the image.

Comment: @Felix, ahh, good call.  I see in your answer how you address that.  Will leave my answer up for my explanation as to why his original solution did not work, but giving yours a +1 to bump it to the top.

Comment: Thank you really much! Closest statement seems really smart!

Answer (score 0):

```
<h3><a href="page.html">Post Title</h3>
```

you forgot to close the anchor tag

it should be

```
<h3><a href="page.html">Post Title</a></h3>
```

See here, it works
http://jsfiddle.net/xu6MX/

Comment: Shame on me!!! I also could use some placeholder images (lorepixum for example)... Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul li").each(function(){
    $("ul li img",this).wrap("<a href='"+ $("h3 a.title",this).attr("href") + "'> </a>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I update the HTML (i've just added class "article" in the first level and close marker "a")

```
<ul>
<li class="article">
    <h3><a class="title" href="page1.html">Post Title 1</a></h3>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="image.png" alt=""/>
            <p>Some text 1</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="article">
    <h3><a class="title" href="page2.html">Post Title 2</a></h3>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="image.png" alt=""/>
            <p>Some text 2</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and here the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".article").each(function(){
        var img = $(this).find('img');
        var title = $(this).find('.title');
        img.wrap("<a href='"+ title.attr("href") + "'></a>");
    });
});
```

NB : For this kind of stuff don't forget instruction "document ready"